# Qt: Simple DOM Model Example Memory Leak

Tags: qt

I think that the [Simple DOM Model Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/itemviews-simpledommodel.html) in Qt has a memory leak.  The following code is used to create the wrapped DomItem objects that are used to track the QDomNodes.

```
DomItem *DomItem::child(int i)
{
     if (childItems.contains(i))
         return childItems[i];  

     if (i >= 0 && i < domNode.childNodes().count()) {
         QDomNode childNode = domNode.childNodes().item(i);
         DomItem *childItem = new DomItem(childNode, i, this);
         childItems[i] = childItem;
         return childItem;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I don't see how the `if` condition actually prevents a previously created wrapper from being overwritten in the `QHash<int,DomItem*>` that's used.  Here is the class definition:

```
class DomItem
{
public:
    DomItem(QDomNode &node, int row, DomItem *parent = 0);
    ~DomItem();
    DomItem *child(int i);
    DomItem *parent();
    QDomNode node() const;
    int row();

private:
    QDomNode domNode;
    QHash<int,DomItem*> childItems;
    DomItem *parentItem;
    int rowNumber;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of the method, `if (childItems.contains(i)) return childItems[i];`, will prevent items in the hash from being overwritten.